# Method not allowed for requested URL

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to upload file from my flask site,but it keeps returning the error
`method is not allowed for the requested URL`. Even my teacher does not have the answer to this question. According to him he has never seen this error. really appreciate your help

my HTML file is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title> Data Collector App </title>
  <head>
    <link href="../static/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Data Collector</h1>
        <form action={{url_for('index')}} method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name="file">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Python srcipt is

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file, url_for
import pandas
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/index')
def upload():
    if method == "POST":
        file=request.files['file']
        file.save(secure_filename("new"+file.filename))
        return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add any allowed methods to a route in the decorator, e.g.

```py
@app.route('/index', methods=['POST', ...])
```

EDIT:
You should probably also check on the `method` field of `request` instead of just `method`.

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Comment: well thanks a lot...i also changed jinja 2 script url_for()

<form action={‌{url_for(upload')}} method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

url_for will call the upload   function as created in the Python script

def upload():

Answer (score 1):

By default routes only accept the `GET` method. If you want your route to answer to other methods, pass a custom `methods` parameter to `@app.route` as follows

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST',])
...

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST',])
...
```

Source https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#http-methods